# How to count the replacement times in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Here is what I am doing:

```
val a = listOf("foo bar", "foo bar baz", "bar", "bar")
val b = a.count {it.contains("bar")}
val aa = a.map { it.replace("bar", "baz") }
var c = aa.count {it.contains("bar")}
println("replaced: ${b-c}")
```

It seems that is not efficient.

BTW, I just found I cann't match whitespace in regex of Java/Kotlin easily, just saying.

Comment: Isn’t c always 0?

Comment: what keeps you from using \s for white space characters? see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's one suggestion: `partition` your list into elements that contain "bar" and elements which don't. Take the first collection and replace the corresponding elements (also count them) and then add back the other elements (not containing "bar").

```
val a = listOf("foo bar", "foo bar baz", "bar", "bar")
var replaced = 0
val replacedList = a.partition { it.contains("bar") }.let {
    it.first.map { it.replace("bar", "baz") }.also { replaced = it.size } +
            it.second
}
println(replaced) //4
println(replacedList) //[foo baz, foo baz baz, baz, baz]
```

Here’s what `partition` does:

> ```
> inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.partition(
>     predicate: (T) -> Boolean
> ): Pair<List<T>, List<T>> (source)
> ```
>
> Splits the original collection into pair of lists, where first list
>   contains elements for which predicate yielded true, while second list
>   contains elements for which predicate yielded false.

EDIT:

If you want to count the total number of occurrences of "bar" instead of the number of strings that contain "bar", the following would work (with blank as the only allowed sparator):

```
val replacedList = a.partition { it.contains("bar") }.let { partitions ->
        partitions.first.map { it.replace("bar", "baz") }.also {
            replaced = partitions.first.flatMap { it.split(" ") }.count { it.contains("bar") }
        } + partitions.second
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, it was midnight,  creative and enlightening, just a little bit of complicate, maybe manually replace with a loop should be used. Thanks.